# Backslash expression to add an underscore at the end of a word?

Tags: regex, scite

I have a huge list of words where every one is in a new line. 
I'm currently using the text editor [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) which can perform backslash expressions. 
Which expression do I need to use to add a **_** (underscore) at the end of each word?
This is an example list:

```
hello
world
foo
bar
```

This is how it should look like:

```
hello_
world_
foo_
bar_
```

Answer (score 0):

With the "regular expression" checkbox active:

- if there is a single word by line, you can simply replace `$` by `_`.
- to tell exactly to append the underscore to each word: replace `\>` by `_`